# Is there any way to get my latest comments using YouTube Data API?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to fetch the videos I have commented on ordered in descending order by time. Though there is channel threads endpoint to fetch latest comments on a video, I couldn't find any way to get my comments on any videos. Other APIs, such as: subscriptions and likes provides this feature where passing `mine=True` argument solves this use case. But for comments and comment threads I couldn't find anything similar.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no YouTube Data API endpoint that'll provide the info you need.

Comment: Finally [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76955655) to this question is available.